# Scatter plot labeling on categorical variable column ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here Im trying to do a scatter plot and trying to label only those features which are `2^sd(residuals)`

Here is my data small set

```
dput(c)
structure(list(Symbol = c("CTD-2326C4.1", "RP11-541M12.6", "RP11-568J23.2", 
"CTC-312O10.3", "AC002044.3", "RP11-49K24.3", "MIR4697HG", "RP11-630A13.4", 
"RP11-1110F20.1", "RP11-80P20.3", "DBNDD1", "SARM1", "ACSM3", 
"COPZ2", "PRKAR2B"), Inter_good = c(-1.58939474887221, 1.69067143806302, 
1.16272382521224, 2.20145652526691, -1.57068808916146, 1.08473475381231, 
-1.5565760616485, 1.07719138691427, 2.59625182296151, 1.40402170916536, 
-1.52458643228586, 1.02335885723362, -1.12350765154002, 1.53586139998766, 
1.82352949605315), Poor_good = c(-1.87518197493689, 1.81130441059405, 
1.79808591248711, 1.39949394735816, -2.06718610513002, 1.20799300027021, 
-1.19642510052193, 1.65505108315884, 1.85022430533524, 1.3007385250318, 
-1.35755750794873, 1.26178439956468, -1.89762330533538, 1.06381047498678, 
1.65314202569446), residuals = c(0.240887793186567, 0.21643114843019, 
0.299667558924424, 1.09635826839287, 0.431704686232931, 0.151295682884655, 
0.334723160744862, 0.256985266497353, 1.08712419961056, 0.387446645842676, 
0.158296345514071, 0.0417018116472507, 0.726891033892134, 0.731665840876596, 
0.491064099192696), group = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE)), row.names = c(1214L, 1215L, 1216L, 1217L, 1218L, 1219L, 
1220L, 1221L, 1222L, 1223L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code to generate the above data

```
regres_data$residuals = abs(lm(Inter_good~Poor_good,data=regres_data)$residuals)
regres_data$group = regres_data$residuals > 2*sd(regres_data$residuals)
```

My code to plot

```
ggplot(regres_data1, aes(x= Inter_good, y= Poor_good))+
   geom_point(aes(colour = group), size=.9) +
   geom_text_repel(aes(label=Symbol),hjust=0, vjust=0) + 
   geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=0.1) +
   theme(legend.position="bottom",
         legend.title=element_blank())
```

What is get is this here everything is getting labelled which seems very clumsy and not useful

My objective is only label those which are having value `TRUE` in the group column.

[image]

Comment: You can use `geom_text_repel(data = ~ subset(.x, group == TRUE), ...)` or use `aes(label = ifelse(group == TRUE, Symbol, ""))`.

Comment: let me run it quick

Comment: This could almost be in [accidental_aRt](https://twitter.com/accidental__art) ;)

Comment: @bretauv is that good or bad enough to make it there?

Comment: @PesKchan it depends if you want to see the glass half full or half empty